# About the validity of a new conjecture about a diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, diophantine-equations

Let us consider the following conjecture:

**Conjecture**: There are no integer solutions of the equation $$x^{y-z}z^{x-y}=y^{x-z}$$ with $x,y,z$ distinct positive integers greater than or equal to $2$.

I came across this result when studying some diophantine equations. Several attempts were made to find a solution, but without any success. By this question I want to see if someone can give me a conterexample to this conjecture.

Comment: What do you know of the solutions? Can you show any properties or conclusions about them?  Gerhard "Prefers Not Reinventing A Wheel" Paseman, 2017.12.05.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Unfortunately, the answer is No. I have no idea on that problem.

Comment: Wlog z <x,y and divide by z^(x-z) Then you can peove that z must be a divisor of x and also y. Then put x=az, y=bz and simplify.

Comment: @user35593: Can you elaborate with this. I cannot reach the point.

Comment: The situation is not that symmetric. I think you have to consider cases.  Gerhard "Already Lost Some Generality Today" Paseman, 2017.12.05.

Comment: Wlog x>y>z and gcd(x,z)=1. We have ( x/y)^(y-z)=(y/z)^(x-y). Let p be a prime and a,b,c the exponents in the prime factorization of x,y,z. Then we must have (y-z)/(x-y)=(b-c)/(a-b)... to be continued

Comment: By symmetry we can assume $x<y<z$ without loss of generality. Or alternatively we can assume $x^{y-z}<y^{z-x}<z^{x-y}$ without loss of generality; making $x^{y-z}<1$ and $z^{x-y}>1$

Comment: That 2nd inequality gives us an ordering on $x,y,z$

Comment: I just added two new proofs, both very neat (but not mine). See at the end of my original post.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The conjecture is true, in fact the equation has no solution in distinct positive real numbers. To see this, let us write the equation in the more symmetric form
$$ x^y y^z z^x = x^z y^x z^y. \tag{$\ast$}$$
We get the same equation after interchanging $x$ and $y$, or $y$ and $z$, i.e., after permuting the variables arbitrarily. Hence we can assume without loss of generality that $x>y>z>0$. Then, with the notation $a:=x-y$ and $b:=y-z$, the original equation becomes
$$ (y+a)^b (y-b)^a = y^{a+b}, $$
where each factor and each exponent is positive. Equivalently,
$$ (1+a/y)^b (1-b/y)^a = 1, $$
where each factor and each exponent is positive. However, this is impossible, since
$$ (1+a/y)^b (1-b/y)^a < (e^{a/y})^b (e^{-b/y})^a = 1.$$

**Added on 22 January 2021.** Recently I posted the equation $(\ast)$ to a non-professional discussion board, and to my surprise two entirely new solutions arose. They are not mine, but I sketch them here as they are really nice and instructive. I will assume that $x,y,z>0$ are distinct and $(\ast)$ holds. I will derive a contradiction in two new ways.

**First new proof (sketch).** By assumption, $u:=y/x$ and $v:=z/x$ satisfy $u^{v-1}=v^{u-1}$. This contradicts (after some thought) the fact that the function $t\mapsto\frac{\ln t}{t-1}$ is strictly decreasing on the positive axis (the function is not defined at $t=1$, but it extends analytically there).

**Second new proof (sketch).** By assumption, the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&x&\ln x\\1&y&\ln y\\1&z&\ln z\\\end{vmatrix}$$
vanishes, hence its rows are linearly dependent. This contradicts (after some thought) the fact that the function $t\mapsto\ln t$ is strictly concave on the positive axis.

Comment: That is a neat solution!